# Blackberry: cannot find symbol symbol : method pushScreen(main.startApp)

Tags: java, blackberry, methods, symbols

As you can see I have a 'main' folder in which i have startApp.java. When my application starts,  it gives user a button. When the is clicked I am trying to do 
pushScreen(new startApp()); . When I do that I get the error 
cannot find symbol    symbol  : method pushScreen(main.startApp)

```
class FieldListener extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
    public void fieldChanged(Field f, int context){
         if (f == btnOne){                  
                pushScreen(new startApp());             
        }

     }
}

public class startApp extends MainScreen {

      public startApp () {  

              Dialog.alert("Coming Soon!");
        }
}
```

My startApp currently looks like above

I have read the whole forum here as well as others and fixed a lot of mistakes which I had made. At this point I am at a loss..why I am getting this error.

Thank you

Comment: UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new startApp()); did it

Answer (score 0):

While pushing your screen to stack, use:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new startApp());
```

pushscreen is a method of UiApplication class.If you dont refer to this class while using "pushscreen" the compiler surely cant find this symbol...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UiApplication.getApplication();
synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new startApp());
}//end synchronized
```